# Exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Hi I'm trying to use HttpURLConnection to send some POST data to a server using the HttpURLConnection class as shown below but it is throwing "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected." at the code - `conn.setRequestProperty(eachEntry.getKey(), eachEntry.getValue());` in the below code. Can any one pls suggest what mistake I am doing here. Also the similar .setRequestPorperty, I am using in other places and it is fine but only when iterating list of request property inside the loop, facing this issue as here.

```
public boolean createAsyncPostRestConnection(boolean isdatabagAvailable, Map<String, Object> databag, String lbrurl,
                                             String apiURL, String componentName, HashMap<String, String> requestProperty) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        // This check is when we have the databag but it is empty. Databag is not mandatory to invoke this function.
        if (isdatabagAvailable && databag.isEmpty()) {
            logger.error("Databag is empty.");
            return false;
        }
        lbrurl = ContentPatchUtils.removeSlash(lbrurl);
        URL url = new URL(lbrurl + apiURL);
        conn = podConfigUtil.getUrlConnection(url);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty(Constants.AUTHRORIZATION, BaseUtil.getPrivateAPIAuthHeader());
        logger.info("The header attribute:" + conn.getHeaderFields());

        if (!requestProperty.isEmpty()) {
            logger.info("Setting the request property now." + requestProperty);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> eachEntry : requestProperty.entrySet()) {
                logger.info("eachEntry.getKey():"+ eachEntry.getKey() +",eachEntry.getValue():"+eachEntry.getValue());
                conn.setRequestProperty(eachEntry.getKey(), eachEntry.getValue());
            }
        }


        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        logger.info("The URL formed is :" + conn.getURL());
        JSONObject payload = new JSONObject(databag);
        try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
            byte[] input = payload.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
        }
        logger.info("Harish,OutputStream write is done.");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED) {
            logger.info(componentName + " ,is invoked successfully.");
            return true;

        } else {
            logger.info(componentName + ",API invocation failed. " +
                    "HTTP code: " + conn.getResponseCode() + ";" +
                    "Response Message: " + conn.getResponseMessage() + ";");
            return false;
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Connection could not be created. The exception trace is ", e);
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            logger.info("disconnecting the connection ");
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is a result of the following log call:

```
logger.info("The header attribute:" + conn.getHeaderFields());
```

`HttpURLConnection#getHeaderFields` is inherited from `URLConnection` which describes the method as returning the **response** headers ([see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderFields--)).

Therefore, I assume when you call `conn.getHeaderFields()`, the `HttpURLConnection` connects and returns you the response header fields. This stops you from being able to edit the request properties of the connection as the connection has already been established - resulting in the error you are experiencing.

Comment: Agreed, I looked in `setRequestProperty` method of `URLConnection` and the first thing there is `checkConnected` which throws the `IllegalStateException` if `connection` is not null. I think the connection is happening at `conn = podConfigUtil.getUrlConnection(url);` line in the code though, but it is hard to tell without knowing the type of `podConfigUtil` :)

Comment: @ferrouskid I think you are confusing the connection in the asker's code with the internal connection of the URLConnection class. `conn = podConfigUtil.getUrlConnection(url);` cannot be the source of the error because they are able to call `setRequestProperty` on the connection after that line - but not after they call `conn.getHeaderFields()`.

Comment: Maybe you are right :) But I have a suspicion they may assume that the exception arises at that point, but it's actually arising earlier. We could know for sure if the log actually contains `Setting the request property now.` message. (I've made this kind of incorrect assumption many times myself, which is why I am suspicious ahah)

Comment: I'll have to disagree, their code seems to work as they intended until it connects without them realising (due to retrieving the response headers). There is a four-step numbered process at the top of the [URLConnection documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), the asker here is accidentally proceeding to step three then trying to retreat back to step two.

Comment: @Ben, you were right ! It worked. Thanks.

Comment: Really appreciate for the quick discussion and response. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean now (I ran a little test in my IDE). Thanks for the explanation!